# Excel Problem: How to implement index match in nested if statements?

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, excel-formula, excel-match

I'm having trouble getting my excel formula to work. The first half of it works fine but the other half keeps giving #N/A. I'm trying to index match a value from a column based on latitude and longitude coordinates from another column in a different worksheet.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is reformat a data sheet I've been given. The data has been formatted so that there are only 20 rows including the headings, and columns are aligned "Direction", "LAT 1", "LONG 1","HEIGHT","TYPE","LAT 2", "LONG 2", "HEIGHT" and "TYPE". What I'm trying to do is only have the 5 columns, (direction, lat, long, height and type). My problem is that I can easily copy the data but everything after the 1st set doesn't have a direction value unless you painstakingly do it manually.

I've tried to use a nested if function with an index match to get the direction values for the remaining rows. Something like:

```
=IF(LAT&LONG=LAT1&LONG1, 
INDEX(VALUE,MATCH(),1),IF(LAT&LONG=LAT2&LONG2,INDEX(VALUE,MATCH(),1),)
```

I'm expecting to get the same results for direction for the first set of GPS coordinates as the second, but the second keeps giving me errors. I should note that I am trying to find the exact direction corresponding to a unique GPS coordinate, this is why I using concatenate.

Any help is appreciated. I can provide more info if needed.

Thanks

**Edit:**

OG Data format

```
|Direction|Lat 1|Long 1|Height|Type|Lat 2|Long 2|Height|Type|
```

Reformatted Data

```
| Direction | Lat | Long | Height | Type |
```

The code being used is as follows:

```
=IF(B1:B38&C1:C38='[OG Data.xlsx]Data'!$B1:$B20&'[OG 
Data.xlsx]Data'!$C1:$C20,INDEX('[OG 
Data.xlsx]Data'!$A1:$A20,MATCH(B21&C21,'[OG Data.xlsx]Data'!$B1:$B20&'[OG 
Data.xlsx]Data'!$C1:$C20,0),1),IF(B1:B38&C1:C38='[OG 
Data.xlsx]Data'!$F1:$F20&'[OG Data.xlsx]Data'!$G1:$G20,INDEX('[OG 
Data.xlsx]Data'!$A1:$A20,MATCH(B21&C21,'[OG Data.xlsx]Data'!$F1:$F20&'[OG 
Data.xlsx]Data'!$G1:$G20,0),1),"FALSE"))
```

Comment: Can you show us which bit does not work? Splitting it down into component parts often makes the error / solution almost self-evident.

Comment: @SolarMike I believe it has something to do with the match function used in the first index when trying to get the direction for the second set of columns. It returns a #N/A, as there is no value in the lookup array that matches.

Comment: We need to see some data rows values for both input 9 column,  and resulting 5 column expected results.  Trying to decode a formula that is admittedly not working is impossible.